# Flutter the values in the array all become the same

Tags: arrays, flutter

Please understand that I am not good at English because I am a foreigner.
There was a problem while I was programming.
I was going to put each object in the array. We succeeded in putting the object in. But there was a problem with all the objects in the array being the same.
I want to solve this problem.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

[image: GIF showing current behaviour in app]

Main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Page/FirstPage.dart';
import 'Page/FourPage.dart';
import 'Page/SecondPage.dart';
import 'Page/ThirdPage.dart';
import 'module/goal.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Index()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Goal('None')),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GoalList())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Todo App',
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  var currentTab = [FirstPage(), SecondPage(), ThirdPage(), FourPage()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Index currentIndex = Provider.of<Index>(context);
    Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex.currentIndex,
        children: currentTab,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex.currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          currentIndex.currentIndex = index;
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        // 하단바 아이콘 고정
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle), title: Text('Todo Create')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
              title: Text('Todo List')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text('none')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('none')),
        ],
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
        // 선택된 index 색깔
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        // 선택안된 index 색깔
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Goal.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

// 아이콘 설정 , 제목 , 기간 ,
class Goal with ChangeNotifier {
  String _name;

  String get getName => _name;
  set setName(String name)=> _name = name;
  Goal(this._name);
  @override String toString() => _name;
}

class Index with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  get currentIndex => _currentIndex;

  set currentIndex(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class GoalList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Goal> goalList = [];
  Goal getGoal;
  addGoalInList() {
    goalList.add(getGoal);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

FirstPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:goalapp/module/goal.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

// 객체를 만들 클래스를 생성
// 생성된 객체를 내부저장소에 저장
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _names = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _names.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Index currentIndex = Provider.of<Index>(context);
    Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
    GoalList goalList = Provider.of<GoalList>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo add'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _names,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: 'Todo Name'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  goal.setName = _names.text;
                  goalList.getGoal = goal;
                  goalList.addGoalInList();
                  currentIndex.currentIndex = 1;
                },
                child: Text('Create'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SecondPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:goalapp/module/goal.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
    GoalList goalList = Provider.of<GoalList>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Todo ListView'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Consumer<GoalList>(builder: (context, goal, child) {
                return ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: goal.goalList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(goalList.goalList[index].getName),
                        subtitle: Text('2020.07.16 ~ 2020.08.16'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                );
              }),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(goalList.goalList[0]);
              },
              child: Text('List[0]'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(goalList.goalList[1]);
              },
              child: Text('List[1]'),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Change `GoalList`'s addGoalInList(Goal goal)

```
class GoalList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Goal> goalList = [];
  Goal getGoal;
  addGoalInList(Goal goal) {
    goalList.add(goal);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Step 2: You do not need `Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Index currentIndex = Provider.of<Index>(context);
   // Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
```

Step 3: Add goal with `Goal goal = Goal(_names.text);` then `goalList.addGoalInList(goal);`

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Goal goal = Goal(_names.text);
      //goal.setName = _names.text;
      //goalList.getGoal = goal;

      goalList.addGoalInList(goal);
      currentIndex.currentIndex = 1;
    },
    child: Text('Create'),
  )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

// 아이콘 설정 , 제목 , 기간 ,
class Goal with ChangeNotifier {
  String _name;

  String get getName => _name;
  set setName(String name)=> _name = name;
  Goal(this._name);
  @override String toString() => _name;
}

class Index with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  get currentIndex => _currentIndex;

  set currentIndex(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class GoalList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Goal> goalList = [];
  Goal getGoal;
  addGoalInList(Goal goal) {
    goalList.add(goal);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

// 객체를 만들 클래스를 생성
// 생성된 객체를 내부저장소에 저장
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _names = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _names.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Index currentIndex = Provider.of<Index>(context);
   // Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
    GoalList goalList = Provider.of<GoalList>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo add'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _names,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: 'Todo Name'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Goal goal = Goal(_names.text);
                  //goal.setName = _names.text;
                  //goalList.getGoal = goal;

                  goalList.addGoalInList(goal);
                  currentIndex.currentIndex = 1;
                },
                child: Text('Create'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
    GoalList goalList = Provider.of<GoalList>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Todo ListView'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Consumer<GoalList>(builder: (context, goal, child) {
                return ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: goal.goalList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(goalList.goalList[index].getName),
                        subtitle: Text('2020.07.16 ~ 2020.08.16'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                );
              }),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(goalList.goalList[0]);
              },
              child: Text('List[0]'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(goalList.goalList[1]);
              },
              child: Text('List[1]'),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Index()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Goal('None')),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GoalList())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Todo App',
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  var currentTab = [FirstPage(), SecondPage()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Index currentIndex = Provider.of<Index>(context);
    Goal goal = Provider.of<Goal>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex.currentIndex,
        children: currentTab,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex.currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          currentIndex.currentIndex = index;
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        // 하단바 아이콘 고정
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle), title: Text('Todo Create')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
              title: Text('Todo List')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text('none')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('none')),
        ],
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
        // 선택된 index 색깔
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        // 선택안된 index 색깔
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I compared the existing code with the code you gave me.
I know what the problem was.
Thank you very much.